# A question about unipotent characters

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, characters

I have just started learning (complex) character theory of groups of Lie type and there are some misunderstandings for me in the subject. It is well-known that unipotent characters of $PGL_{n_i}(q_i)$ (and $PSL_{n_i}(q_i)$), where $q_i=p^{r_i}$, are in one-to-one correspondance with the partitions of number $n_i$. My question is about unipotent characters of some specific groups lying between the finite direct products $\coprod_{i} PSL_{n_i}(q_i)$ and $\coprod_{i} PGL_{n_i}(q_i)$, namely the centralizers of semisimple elements. 
 
 If we consider a semisimple element $s \in SL_n(q)$, then there exist inegers $n_i$ and $r_i$ with $\Sigma n_ir_i=n$ such that $PSL_{n_1}(q^{r_1})\times...\times PSL_{n_k}(q^{r_k}) \leq \overline{C_{SL_n(q)}(s)} \leq  PGL_{n_1}(q^{r_1})\times...\times PGL_{n_k}(q^{r_k})$, where $\overline{C_{SL_n(q)}(s)}$ is the image of $C_{SL_n(q)}(s)$, the centralizer of $s$ in $SL_n(q)$, under the canonical homomorphism $-:\coprod_{i=1}^{k}{GL_{n_i}}\rightarrow \coprod_{i=1}^{k}{PGL_{n_i}}$.
  
 
  Let $PSL_{n_1}(q_1)\times...\times PSL_{n_k}(q_k) \leq H \leq  PGL_{n_1}(q_1)\times...\times PGL_{n_k}(q_k)$, such that $H=\overline{C_{SL_n(q)}(s)}$ for a semisimple element $s\in SL_n(q)$, where $n=\Sigma n_ir_i$ and $q_i=q^{r_i}$. ($-$ is canonical morphism as above) . Also let $\mathbb{U}(G)$ denotes the set of unipotent characters of group $G$.
  
  **Question:** Is it true that $\mathbb{U}(PSL_{n_1}(q_1)\times...\times PSL_{n_k}(q_k))= \mathbb{U}(H)$?
  
   I know that by a result of George Lusztig, all unipotent characters of $PSL_{n_i}(q_i)$ are extendable to $PGL_{n_i}(q_i)$, and also unipotent characters of $PGL_{n_i}(q_i)$ remain irreducible upon restriction to $PSL_{n_i}(q_i)$. This implies that $\mathbb{U}(PGL_{n_1}(q_1)\times...\times PGL_{n_k}(q_k))=\mathbb{U}(PSL_{n_1}(q_1)\times...\times PSL_{n_k}(q_k)) \subset \mathbb{U}(H)$.
  Now assuming that the claim in the question is true, how can I show that $H$ does not have any other unipotent character outside $\mathbb{U}(PSL_{n_1}(q_1)\times...\times PSL_{n_k}(q_k))$? If the claim is false, would you please provide a counterexample?
  I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: What is your definition of unipotent characters of $H$? I ask this because for me, unipotent characters only appear in the context of finite groups derived from (connected reductive) linear algebraic groups via a rational structure.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch I have made question more specific by restricting $H$ just to the centralizers. Now the unipotent characters must be meaningful for $H$ as they mean in Lusztig's parametrization of irreducible characters of $PGL_n$.

Comment: ‎It ‎is ‎known ‎by ‎Deligne-Lusztig ‎theory ‎that ‎‎irreducible ‎characters ‎‎‎‎of‎ ‎$G:=‎PGL_n(q)$ ‎are ‎in ‎bijection ‎with ‎the ‎set ‎of ‎pairs‎ ‎$(\chi_s, \psi_s)$, ‎where‎ ‎$\chi_s$ ‎is ‎the ‎semisimple ‎character ‎of‎ ‎$G$‎ corresponding to the semisimple element ‎$s\in G^*:=SL_n(q)$, ‎and ‎‎$\psi_s$ ‎is a ‎‎‎unipotent ‎character ‎of‎ ‎$C_{G^*}(s)$.

Comment: I believe you should try to compare the unipotent characters of $C_{SL_n(q)}(s)$ with the unipotent characters of $C_{GL_n(q)}(s)$. In fact, $C_{GL_n(q)}(s)$ is a product of groups of the form $GL_{n_i}(q_i)$ and its image in $PGL_n$ is precisely the product of $PGL_{n_i}(q_i)$ which you consider.  You might be interested in Proposition 13.20 of Digne-Michel's 'Representations of Finite Groups of Lie Type' which shows that both centralizers have the same unipotent characters.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Thank you. I will be grateful if you correct me in the following: The centralizers of semisimple elements are reductive but not necessarily connected. Anyway, In the language of Proposition 13.20 of Digne-Michel's book, we can put $G:=C_{SL_n(q)}$ and $G_1:=C_GL_n(q)$. Since $G\leq G_1$, we can take $f$ to be the embedding of $G$ in $G_1$. Now the proposition says that unipotent characters of $C_{SL_n(q)}$ and $C_{GL_n(q)}$ are the same. (To be continued in the next comment...)

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Since unipotent characters have center of group in their kernels, we then deduce that unipotent characters of $H=\overline{C_{SL_n(q)}(s)}$ and $C_{SL_n(q)}$ are the same. This together with the previous result imply that  $H$ and $C_{GL_n(q)}$ have the same unipotent characters. Am I right?

Comment: In general, centralizers need not be connected, that is true, however, in your case, where you consider centralizers of $GL_n$ and $SL_n$ these centralizers are, in fact, connected. The rest of what you said is correct, even though I am still a bit irritated when you write about unipotent characters of $PSL_n$ and $\overline{C_{SL_n(s)}(s)}$, since $PSL_n$ does not immediately come from an algebraic group and so it is not clear to me what unipotent characters should be here.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch You are right. For $PSL_n$, the unipotent characters doesn't have an independent meaning. In fact, they are considered to be the unipotent characters of $SL_n$. However, the term "unipotent characters" for simple groups of Lie type has became a "common phrase" in the literature of many papers these days.

Comment: I see, that is good to know. One thing I overlooked: you should not consider the inclusion $G \leq G_1$ but the inclusion of the corresponding linear algebraic groups and the corresponding embedding.

Comment: Yes, even more general you have $C_{G}(s)^F = G^F \cap C_{G}(s) = C_{G^F}(s)$ for any linear algebraic group $(G,F)$ defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch That's right. So we should put $G:=C_{SL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)}$ and $G_1:=C_{GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)}$, where $\mathbb{F}_q$ is algebraic closed field of characteristic $p$. One point: Is it always true that ${C_{GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)}}^F \cong C_{{GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)}^{F}}$ and ${C_{SL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)}}^F \cong C_{{SL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)}^F}$, where $F:(a_{ij})\mapsto ({a_{ij}}^q)$ is the standard Frobenius map?

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Excuse me, but do you know a reference for the fact that the unipotent characters of $GL_{n_1}(q) \times GL_{n_2}(q)$ are actually products of unipotent characters of $GL_{n_1}(q)$ and $GL_{n_2}(q)$?

Comment: No, I do not. But this is fairly easy to prove, in fact, you can show this for the direct product of any finite reductive groups.